# Creating an unordered list with asp.net controls?

Tags: asp.net, html, webforms

I've got this web control that I've been dynamically adding controls to but now the requirement is to add an ordered list around the controls.

To render the controls I add the controls to ControlsCollection

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var document = XDocument.Load(@"http://localhost:49179/XML/Templatek.xml");
        var builder = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IControlBuilder>();
        var controls =builder.BuildControls(document);
        controls.ToList().ForEach(c => Controls.Add(c));

    }
```

And this is the html+aspnet ctrls I want to build:

```
 <fieldset>
    <ol>
      <li>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
      </li>
      <li>
          <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1"></asp:TextBox>
      </li>
    </ol>
    </fieldset>
```

How do I position the controls in the list items?
Do I need to approach the problem differently?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change this line:

```
controls.ToList().ForEach(c => Controls.Add(c));
```

To these lines:

```
Control ol = new HtmlGenericControl("ol");
controls.ToList().ForEach(c => ol.Controls.Add(new HtmlGenericControl("li").Controls.Add(c)));
Controls.Add(ol);
```

EDIT:

```
    Control ol = new HtmlGenericControl("ol");
    controls.ToList().ForEach(c =>
                                  {
                                      var li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
                                      li.Controls.Add(c);
                                      ol.Controls.Add(li);
                                  });
    Controls.Add(ol);
```

Comment: This code doesn't make sense to me; I think `Controls.Add` returns `void`, so how can you use its result as an argument?

Comment: i'm not attempting to use any result from Controls.Add

Comment: It looks like you are to me; you are trying to use the result of `Controls.Add` as the argument of `ol.Controls.Add`. Your code doesn't compile for me.

Comment: The C# (4) compiler and I both interpret your code as you using the result of `Add` as the argument to `ol.Controls.Add`.

Comment: hmmm. i'm 99% certain this built at one time.  I'm expecting to use the result of the new operator, not the result of Add().

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest to create a tree of HtmlGenericControls:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol.aspx

Comment: Using this class is definitely the way to go.  Not only does it make for clean readable procedural code, it saves you from looking at crazy lambdas to complete such a simple task.

Comment: @afuzzyllama You don't have to use any lambdas. Just use a regular foreach if you'd like. All the lambda syntax is doing is saving you from writing code with a bunch of one time use variables.